# java Change the title of a object everytime I run a for loop NOOB Question

Tags: java

```
    private void drawGrid(){
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        GLine line = new GLine(0,0,21*i,211*i);
        add(line);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change the name of the gline I create each time the for loop is run?

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Why do you need to change the name ?

Comment: I am trying to make each gline have a differant name so that I can add multiple of them

Comment: What exactly is this name/title you want to change anyway?

Comment: I want each line to be called a differant name so that instead of only having one gobject I can have 3 differant ones each one with a distinct name and location

Comment: There is something fundamental here that you are misunderstanding: you are creating 3 distinct objects. The name of the reference "line" doesn't change if they are distinct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of `GLine`, and store a new `GLine` in each index:

```
private void drawGrid(){

   GLine[] glines = new GLine[3];

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        GLine line = new GLine(0,0,21*i,211*i);
        glines [i] = line;
    }
}
```

This way, `glines[0]` referes to the first `GLine`, `glines[1]` refers to the second one etc.